# Do you place a comma before "365 days per year" if it doesn't follow "7 days per week?"

Tags: commas

In other words, which of these sentences would be correct:

> We hold sleeping to the highest value 365 days per year.

OR

> We hold sleeping to the highest value, 365 days per year.

Comment: I'm not even sure what *365 days per year* is supposed to *mean* in the cited context. Are you trying to say that *you **always** think* that sleeping is very important (i.e. - your opinion on the matter doesn't and never would change), or that you think it's important that *people should sleep **every** day?* Or something else? The "clipped" style of the text might pass unnoticed in a spoken context, but it looks awkward and clumsy 
(as well as being ambiguous) in a written context. As to possible punctuation, a (semi)colon, period, or dash might be more approptiate than a comma.

Comment: ...also note that *7 days a week, 365 days a year* is slightly "nonsensical" (strictly speaking, tautologous). If you want to include both weeks *and* years as an emphatic way of saying ***daily** [without exception]*, it would make more sense to say *7 days a week, 52 weeks a year*.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Comma Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/comma) by The Oxford Dictionaries, part of their [Punctuation Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/punctuation).

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the comma, but I don’t think it’s necessarily wrong. It might be ok to place the comma there to create a pause and emphasize “365 days per year.”

The first part of the sentence is not idiomatic, though. Maybe you mean “We hold sleep(ing) *in the highest regard*”? That is an idiomatic expression with the meaning I think you have in mind.